# Update/Replace mongodb document using struct & mongodb/mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I am trying to update/replace a mongodb document using a struct but i keep on getting `err: update document must contain key beginning with '$'`

```
collection := r.client.Database(database).Collection(greetingCollection)
payment.MongoID = objectid.New()
filter := bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("id", payment.ID))
_, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, payment)
return err
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should provide an update statement instead of a document as third parameter to the [`Collection.UpdateOne`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.UpdateOne) method. For example:

```
update := bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
        "$set",
        bson.EC.Double("pi", 3.14159),
    ),
)
collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

See more on the available update operators in the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) (the keys begin with '$').

Comment: One doesn't use bson.M in mongo-go-driver. Please, look at this [example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/71de844febff6ac5b6fc6ba165e24e9677d2ee05/mongo/collection_internal_test.go#L808-L813)

Comment: The example from my understanding just updates a root property on the document called pi?

I wish to replace the whole document with a struct called payment how do i do that?

Comment: If you want to replace use `ReplaceOne` instead of `UpdateOne`

Answer (score 25):

I believe the accepted answer did not work for me because I am using the `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` package. With this package, the syntax is even simpler:

```golang
update := bson.M{
        "$set": yourDocument,
    }

collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

Comment: works like a charm on `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`

Comment: ```update := bson.D{{"$set", document}}``` works too